# Python: While is not working with "or"

Tags: python, while-loop

So, I have this:

```
while cancer[j] != ("l"or"r"or"c")
```

and it's stopping at the first "l" in the way when it has some r and c in between the string, its acting like there are not "or" and only the "l".

for example my string is this one:

```
c56r36c20l80c23l180c23l20c55r70
```

and it returns:

```
c56r36c20
```

It stops right at the first "l", skipping the "c" and "r" in the way.

Comment: `("l" or "r" or "c") == "l"`. You want `cancer not in {'l', 'r', 'c'}`.

Comment: please see in Python documentation how `or` operator works. `'l' or 'r' or 'c'` expression always have value `'l'`. You need the `not in` operator here.

Comment: you need to learn what the `or` operator does logically.

Comment: @JeremyBanks wouldn't `not in "lrc"` work?

Comment: @JeremyBanks never mind, sets are faster :)

Comment: @ReutSharabani not in "lrc" worked like a charm! Thanks !

Comment: @NachoLZ - notice that looking in a set is actually faster, as Jeremy suggested, since it will be using hashes. No reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: with 3 elements, i'd say looking over a tuple is faster, and should be lighter. But the lookup's so fast and the structure dies so quickly it barely matters.

Comment: I still don't get what you are trying to extract from you string. You say that your program is skipping the c and the r. Do you want to extract each number that starts with c, r or l and stop if it starts with something else?

Answer (score 1):

It's working properly; it just doesn't work how you think it should:

```
("l" or "r" or "c")
```

returns the first nonfalse item (`bool(item) is true`) on that list, or false if there isn't any. That means it'll return `"l"`.

So your while loop is actually:

```
while cancer[j] != "l":
```

What you want, instead, is something like:

```
while cancer not in ('l', 'r', 'c')
```

or

```
while not cancer in ('l', 'r', 'c')
```

Both are pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if one of the expressions in an 'or' statement evaluates to `True`, the rest of the expression is not evaluated at all. So when the first 'l' is encountered in the string, the while condition will break right there.

You should have something like:

```
while cancer[j] not in ('l', 'r', 'c'):
```